# Compilation process in Java

Tags: java, compilation, binary, executable

A compilation process takes source code to be translated into machine language.

So far, I have mentioned **.java** files (source code) and **.exe** files (0s and 1s).

> So, **What is the purpose of .class files** that seem to be in the middle of the entire process?

We already have executable files coming from java source code and they don't depend on these .class files.

I know .class files are also created after compilation, but their content (which I don't know) differ from .exe files because they can only run with a java compiler and not as an independent application like an executable file will do.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java was created to be platform independent. .class files contain JVM (Java Virtual Machine) code instead of normal machine code as found in .exes. The JVM is idealized, with features no real processor actually has, but it is less complex than the language of Java itself and is an abstraction layer above the platform specific hardware.

When a Java program is run, the JVM interprets the Java bytecode so that it can actually run on the CPU. The initial javac compilation relieves the JVM from having to compile the entire program on execution and hampering performance, while the abstraction lets the code run anywhere as long as a JVM is installed.

This is in contrast to .exe files, which contain platform specific machine code directly. Windows itself provides abstraction that keeps things from breaking, but because the code is still platform specific it won't work on non-Windows systems and there are separate versions for 32- and 64-bit systems (unless, of course, emulators).

The bytecode interpretation the JVM does is still very expensive compared to .exe files loading machine code directly. Therefore, if some part of the code is called enough, the JIT (Just-In-Time compiler) will kick in and compile the JVM code directly to platform specific machine code and store that in memory to increase performance in these active areas. If that area of code is used enough, the JIT does optimization on that code too, and because it can run profiling on running code it can optimize things with assumptions .exe compilers can't make. This is why many large Java programs have a warmup time before they start working more efficiently.

Comment: Very useful information! Thank you